# Optimizing Real-time Vehicle Tracking System for Non-Chronological Data Streams: Seeking Efficient Recalculation Methods

Tags: postgresql, time-series, gps

I am building a vehicle tracking system which stores a continuous stream of vehicle data as a time series data. The parameters include; timestamp, coordinates (lat,lng), ignition status, speed, angle, power status, etc.

Certain calculations are happening in real-time, viz;

1. distance (the difference between previous and current coordinates,
2. ignition on/off and battery connect/disconnect events (updated when the ignition status and power status changes)

However, a challenge occurs when the data is not received chronologically, i.e. due to network issues data for 1 pm may be received after data for 2 pm is received.

To overcome this problem, whenever past data is received, a recalculation function is run which fetches all the records from the particular moment and iterates through each record to calculate the above events.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Wait a couple of hours before processing the data.

Comment: Please update the post with the associated table DDL (including indexes), sample input data, calculation functions, and expected output. In its current state, the post is too abstract to elicit more than speculative opinions.

Comment: depending on how much this happens, you could maybe either just send the previous few samples along with the current sample (in the hope that this causes things to resynchronise, note that most packet based protocols have some overhead so a few extra bytes of data shouldn't add much overhead). or maybe you could send some confirmation back from the server to the client about what data it received letting the client know how much prior data to send the next time it tries